# Force function argument to be a string

Tags: python, string, function, arguments

So, my code is like this:

```
def func(s,x):
   return eval(s.replace('x',x)

#Example:
>> func('x**2 + 3*x',1)
4
```

The first argument of the function `func` must be a string because the function `eval` accepts only string or code objects. However, I'd like to use this function in a kind of calculator, where the user types for example `2 + sin(2*pi-0.15) + func(1.8*x-32,273)` and gets the answer of the expression, and it's annoying always to have to write the quotes before in the expression inside `func()`.

Is there a way to make python understands the `s` argument is always a string, even when it's not between quotes?

Comment: I had a good idea to to I want: to get the things easier for the user, I could parse the expression before evaluate, and add the quotes during the parsing. In that way the user don't need to type annoying quotes. (I forgot to say the expressions are typed in a text entry of a GUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an interpreter:

```
import code

def readfunc(prompt):
    raw = input(prompt)
    if raw.count(',')!=1:
        print('Bad expression: {}'.format(raw))
        return ''
    s, x = raw.split(',')
    return '''x={}; {}'''.format(x, s)

code.interact('Calc 0.1', readfunc)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. You can't intercept the Python interpreter before it parses and evaluates `1.8*x-32`.

Using `eval` as a glorified calculator is a **highly** questionable idea. The user could pass in all kinds of malicious Python code. **If** you're going to do it, you should provide as minimal an environment as possible for the code to run in. Pass in your own globals `dict` containing only the variables the user is allowed to reference.

```
return eval(s, {'x': x})
```

Besides being safer, this is also a better way to substitute `x` into the expression.

Comment: That dictionary you passed in provides no security at all

Comment: [Ned Batchelder shows](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) that a malicious user can run arbitrary Python functions if given `eval(s, {'x': x})`, or even `eval(s, {'__builtins__': None}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have it handle both cases:

```
def func(s, x=0):
    if isinstance(s, basestring):
        # x is in the scope, so you don't need to replace the string
        return eval(s)
    else:
        return s
```

And the output:

```
>>> from math import *
>>> func('2 + sin(2*pi-0.15) + func(1.8*x-32,273)')
    -30.1494381324736
>>> func('x**2 + 3*x', 1)
    4
```

Caution: `eval` can do more than just add numbers. I can type `__import__('os').system('rm /your/homework.doc')` and your calculator will delete your homework.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: no, if I understand you.

In a few more, you can sort of get around the problem by making `x` be a special object.  This is how the Python math library [SymPy](http://sympy.org) works.  For example:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> x**2+3*x
x**2 + 3*x
>>> (x**2+3*x).subs(x,1)
4
```

There's even a handy function to turn strings into sympy objects:

```
>>> from sympy import sympify, pi
>>> sympify("x**2 - sin(x)")
x**2 - sin(x)
>>> _.subs(x, pi)
pi**2
```

All the warnings about untrusted user input hold.  [I'm too lazy to check whether or not `eval` or `exec` is used on the `sympify` code path, and as they say, every weapon is loaded, even the unloaded ones.]